# Java Class gets added twice to Mylyn context

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I have a Maven multi module project, the parent project is "oscr" with several sub modules, one of them is "oscr-business".

When I create a task and want to add the current Mylyn context to it, each file is added twice, as you can see in the picture:

[image: Mylyn Context]

Note that all four files are displayed under the "oscr-business" project, so it seems that being a sub module is not an issue here.

Of course I would like to get rid of the first two files and only keep the "src/main/java" entry below.

How can I do that?

UPDATE

This is definitely not a Maven multi module problem, but a maven problem, when I create a project in eclipse that is a "Standard Java Project", everything works fine. But already a simple (non-multi-module) maven project shows the wrong behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug, caused by a missing "remove duplicates filter": https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=425554